# Weird Visual bug from CSS3 / jQuery Animation in Chrome for OSX

Tags: jquery, macos, css, google-chrome

#### Link:  I've created a jsFiddle isolating the issue here: http://d.pr/WeYX/Vm065Jeo

### The problem:

When initiating the animation, the parent element with a semi-opaque rgba background goes darker (although, not completely black) for the duration of the animation, then jumps back its original value.

#### Caveats:

The issue is completely circumvented when using a semi-opaque .png instead of an rgba value

#### Libraries being used:

- jQuery 1.10.1
- [jQuery Transit 0.9.9](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

### Browsers tested on:

- Chrome on Mac [10.8.5] - Latest (visual animation bug)
- Chrome on Windows - unknown version (no problems)
- Chrome on Linux - unknown version (no problems)
- Firefox - Latest (sluggish, but no problems)
- Opera - Latest (sluggish, but no problems)
- Safari for Mac - Latest (no problems)

Comment: Try -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);

Comment: Or `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on `.overlay`

Comment: FWIW, both of those suggestions fix it for me :)

Comment: translateZ(0px) enables hardware acceleration. http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/

Comment: @Sigma, Thank you for the recommendation, however I find A. Wolff's comment to be exactly the type of fix I was looking for. If A. Wolff listed his as an answer I would accept it.